# How To Boot Into Raspberry Pi OS's Standard Desktop (PIXEL?)

Tags: desktop

I have a remote, headless Raspberry Pi to which I always connect via SSH. Yesterday I connected via VNC for the first time and was surprised to see an unusual and mostly useless desktop:

[image]

If I enter a password the login box goes away, but I'm left with a blank desktop. I can right-click for a minimal menu of stuff; most of which doesn't work. I would very much like to log in to this desktop, which is the one that my other three remote Pies boot with:

[image]

I have tried raspy-config which changes nothing. I have tried running sudo startx, which fails with many error messages. I also tried update-alternatives:

```
pi@raspmountain:~/webcam $ update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
There is only one alternative in link group x-session-manager (providing /usr/bin/x-session-manager): /usr/bin/openbox-session
Nothing to configure.

pi@raspmountain:~/webcam $ lsb_release -irdc
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Pixel is DEAD, Long Live RPD](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=161246&start=175#p1183248) What OS? Doesn't look like Raspberry Pi OS. Did you enable VNC

Comment: Your IP address must have changed - that's not a headless install. Use Angry IP Scanner or some other tool to see what your actual IP is for the headless installation

Comment: The headless install was done last June or July. I enabled VNC at that time, but had not used it until yesterday when I noticed the odd desktop. I have two other headless Pi 4s also with VNC enabled and both of them have what I'll call the default Raspberry Pi OS desktop, a screenshot of which is in the OP. I don't care what desktop I have as I only want to use it to run SD Card Copier, a GUI app. That app is on the odd "debian" desktop, but if I select it, it doesn't run.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what my IP address as to do with it. Please explain.

Comment: **DO NOT put detail in Comments** EDIT your Question. You can find OS (over `ssh`) with `lsb_release -irdc` . Does the Pi have a screen? How do you expect to use SD Card Copier on a remote machine?

Comment: I put the results of usb_release in the OP. I had a look at the machine now so that I don't have to waste time when I'm at the location figuring out whether or not SD Card Copier is available. I have found that it is not. It's called "planning ahead". (Is that too much detail for a comment?) Now I can figure out how to run SD Card Copier at my leisure instead of in a rush when I'm at the machine's location.